# What's the name of book where copies of people are beamed to other planets?

Tags: story-identification, novel

Does anyone know the name of this book (might be a series)?

- Planets are colonized by people having copies of themselves beamed to the planet.  A person walks into a booth on earth for a few minutes and then goes about their life. On the other planet a copy walks out with all the memories of the original.
- The story line was about how the lives evolve differently and the same limited number of people keep bumping into "themselves." I think I read it in the 70's but think it is older.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Possibly the ['Cuckoo' series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saga_of_Cuckoo) *Farthest Star* (1975) and *Wall Around A Star* (1983).  People are 'beamed' to first, a starship approaching the mysterious object Cuckoo, and later to a station orbiting Cuckoo.  The original people, as you described, step out of the booth and go about their business.

From the wikipedia article linked above:

> The series explores several themes. The most used is the notion of an
>   interstellar teleporter that leaves the original being behind and
>   sends only a duplicate. When a person is duplicated, the original can
>   just pass out of the machine without a second thought. However the
>   duplicate arrives at the destination with the same state of mind as
>   the original, and thus is shocked to realize that he or she is now
>   stranded far from home. Another is the fact that the copies can be
>   'edited' at destination.